# Non-Trivial Solutions To The Partial Differential Equation (Helmholtz).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Use separation of variables to find non-trivial values of $\lambda$ and corresponding solutions for equation below - I have:

$$\frac{\partial^2u }{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u }{\partial y^2}+\lambda u=0$$

> Boundary conditions are

$$u(x,y)=0$$$$0\leq x\leq r,0\leq y\leq r$$$$F(x,y)= X(x)Y(y)$$$$Y\frac{\partial^2X }{\partial x^2}+X\frac{\partial^2Y }{\partial x^2}+k^2XY=0$$$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2X }{\partial x^2}+\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2Y }{\partial x^2}+k^2=0$$$$\frac{1}{X}\frac{\partial^2 X}{\partial x^2}=m^2$$$$\frac{1}{Y}\frac{\partial^2 Y}{\partial x^2}=-(m^2+k^2)$$$$X=A_me^{mx}+B_me^{-mx}$$$$Y=C_me^{yi\sqrt{m^2+k^2}}+D_me^{-yi\sqrt{m^2+k^2}}$$$$Y=E_m\sin (y\sqrt{m^2+k^2})+F_m\cos (y\sqrt{m^2+k^2})$$$$F(x,y)=Y(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty }A_me^{mx}+B_me^{-mx})$$

> But where to from here?